# What's a word for a 'thing that makes one sleepy'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm imagining the sleep equivalent of words like aphrodisiac, appetiser, etc.

For example:

> Oysters are an **aphrodisiac**
>
> Hot drinks are a **{thing that makes one sleepy}**

[thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/sleepy?s=t) doesn't give anything which leads to a suitable noun.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Most contemporary words have already been given, though 'hypnotic' is still used in pharmacology (as when distinguishing sleep-producing effects from sedation); the rest of these words are obscure.

[**hypnotic**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hypnotic) : a drug
which produces sleep (i.e. sedative)

**dwale** : a stupefying or soporific drink (often specifically Belladonna) [TFD]

**sopient** : a soporific agent (medical) [OED]

[**somnifacient**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/somnifacient) a
drug or other agent that induces sleep.

**somniferic** : a soporific [seemingly conflated as another form of the adj somniferous, but cited as an obsolete noun by OED]

**somnificator** : a person who induces sleep [OED, rare]

**somnivolency** : a thing intended as a soporific (pl. somnivolencies) [OED, rare;  a *somnivolent* is also one who desires]
to sleep

**somnoriferous**/**somnorific** : adj. soporific, as said of an agent [OED, obs]

**soporative** : obs form of soporific [OED]

And a few more adjectives, since they can be easily made to refer to such a thing:

somniculous, somnific, somnifying, soporous,

Comment: This was most useful for me, given what I was trying to express. Thanks!

Comment: What about, "the itis"? http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=the+Itis ;  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNh_mQo9fXo

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer: good call on the cultural reference, but it's on the wrong side of the concept in question. "The Itis" is really a synonym for the *state of sleepiness*, while the question asked for the general name of agents which *cause* this state. While *ribs* or *turkey* would be a specific example, the general class of sleep-promoting food might fall under something already mentioned, such as *soporific*.

Comment: @TwoSheds thanks for considering my suggestion. I rebuttal your statement with: I don't think "the itis" is really a synonym for _the state of sleepiness_  because it is only brought on by consumption of said specific examples. One wouldn't say they have "the itis" after a long days work, therefore, I believe "the itis" is a cause, just like not everyone, nor every time, that you eat ribs or turkey, do you feel sleepy. Only in cases where one has contracted "the itis" does sleepiness start to incur. :-)

Comment: Yes, this is a good call again. Calling it a synonym is not necessarily precise: it's an *example* of a state of sleepiness, so is only a synonym in both directions if the causation meets criteria. But the point about it being on the wrong side of cause/effect still stands ^^

Answer (score 91):

[Soporific](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/SOporific), or *soporiferous*:

> - Inducing or tending to induce sleep.
> - Drowsy.

(AHD)

- The professor’s boring speech was soporific and had everyone in the audience yawning.
- Because of the medicine’s soporific properties, the doctor told me to only take it at bedtime.

Comment: The word is adjectival in form, but is often used as a noun to mean a soporific *medicine,* as in "She prescribed him a single dose of a potent soporific."

Comment: Yep, as soon as I saw the question I said "soporific".  I think it's fairly well known and understood.

Comment: Used in Beatrix Potter - The Flopsy Bunnies.

Comment: Like this answer?

Comment: @hosch250 - or rather The Tale of the Flopsy Bunnies. It means that it is probably more widely known amongst English speakers (who were brought up with that book) than it's relatively rare usage might lead you to believe.

Comment: @FrancisDavey Yes, it isn't used very much in real life.

Comment: Some cold treatments sold in the UK advertise themselves as "non drowsy".

Comment: Soporific is a bit archaic if not entirely Shakespearian, but you came here for English, not Ancient Greek. καρώδης is the Greek and clearly no English stems from that. Soporific works great.

Comment: @CommaToast - I don't think that it is that archaic!!https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=soporific+&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csoporific%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Yes - while basically correct, 'soporific' is typically only used as an adjective which could momentarily cause confusion in the reader. That seems to be the case for all the well-fitting words in this case, so I'd rather use a word that isn't commonly used at all, like 'dormative' or 'somnolent', perhaps.

Comment: @TSwire, I respectfully disagree, because anyone well-read enough to already know the meaning of "soporific" would not likely be the type of person to get thrown off by its use as a noun — and anyone who googles it will instantly see its definition as a noun at the top of the search results.

Comment: @Josh61 All I said was that it's "a bit" archaic...

Answer (score 31):

'Sedative' is a word for a thing (substance, pill, medicine, drug) that makes one sleepy, because it induces (or tends to induce) sleep.

Comment: It also works for non-medications, like "Dr. Slocombe's lecture on the sociopolitical implications of foot fungus is an effective sedative."

Comment: Sedation is the reduction of irritability or agitation. A sedative does not necessarily make you sleepy.

Comment: Depressant is what came to mind, as in the opposite of a stimulant (like caffeine) that keeps you awake, a depressant makes you tired.

Answer (score 13):

You might like to consider

**Dormitive** - From [Websters](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Dormitive) - A substance that causes sleep; a soporific.
or
**Dormifacient** - ([Medical Term](http://medicine.academic.ru/119101/dormifacient)) That which brings about sleep or aids in attaining sleep; "a dormifacient agent".

Answer (score 4):

Since you appear to be looking for a noun, I would say *narcoleptic* is your word.

Comment: This seems a good answer to the question. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/narcoleptic: a soporific drug that produces an uncontrollable desire to sleep.

Comment: IMO, "narcoleptic" is much stronger than just "makes you sleepy". "Hypnotic" or "soporific" are the better choices.

Comment: Use this one with caution: *narcoleptic* more often describes a person afflicted with *narcolepsy*. Such a person is prone to falling asleep, but a narcoleptic person doesn't cause anyone to feel sleepy. Without clarification, this could easily lead to confusion.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is [*narcotic:*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/narcotic)

> 1 a :  a drug (as opium or morphine) that in moderate doses dulls the senses, relieves pain, and induces profound sleep but in excessive doses causes stupor, coma, or convulsions

(Definition from merriam-webster.com)

Comment: narcotic would not apply in this case, although narcotics do induce sleep sometimes, they are more to be used as extreme pain killers.

Comment: @x-x - Agreed, it's not the go-to choice, for the reason you stated; I included it here for the sake of completeness.

Comment: also for the sake of completeness: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hypnotic

Comment: @x-x the fact that the word "narcotic" refers to a class of drugs which are primarily employed today as pain killers does not at all obviate the fact that the older meaning of the adjective "narcotic" -- after which that class of drugs was (perhaps mistakenly) named -- is, quite literally, "sleep-inducing".  From the [Greek root 'narkóō'](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/narco-).

Comment: @Codeswitcher I was not aware of the roots, only of the current use of the word.

Comment: @TSwire There's a reason sleep aids that are 'non-habit forming' don't work; they don't contain narcotics.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a modern, neologian spin, I'd invent with "hybernetic" or "torporant" ...

"He imbibed a noxious hybernetic and could nigh be shocked to for days."

"The liquor, a decided torporant, reduced him to felinity within minutes."

~ me

PS — these ain't in the dictionary... not yet anyway. But what is English if not a neologian's frolickeria?

Comment: Neologician or novovocabulist?